# How to detect if a Gradle build is running on TeamCity?

Tags: gradle, teamcity

[Some log messages](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/service-messages.html) in my build scripts are only relevant when the Gradle build is running on TeamCity. How do detect programmatically if the Gradle build is running on TeamCity or not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be done using [environment variables corresponding to TeamCity's server build parameters](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/predefined-build-parameters.html#Server+Build+Properties), quote:

> | Environment variable name | Description |
> | --- | --- |
> | TEAMCITY_VERSION | The version of the TeamCity server. This property can be used to determine if the build is run within TeamCity. |

To do it in a Gradle script, [method `java.lang.System#getenv(java.lang.String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getenv-java.lang.String-) can be used:

```java
boolean isOnTeamCity = System.getenv("TEAMCITY_VERSION") != null
```